# SSO for Wirecloud/IdM and Moodle?

Tags: moodle, fiware, fiware-wirecloud, moodle-api

Looking for best practice instructions on how to integrate a Fiware/Wirecloud with Moodle. It would seem that Fiware/IdM should be providing the user data and Moodle connects via one of its plugins. Moodle offers a number of different authentication options (actually too many, difficult to decide best path). Ideally, once logged in, Moodle pluggins should also be able to access other FIWARE backend services.

Should be possible in principle but I notice that the Fiware academy http://edu.fiware.org/ does *not* have SSO with the FIWARE lab :-)

Comment: so the community is waiting for you to write this plugin. Look at oauth2 plugins as a base.

Answer (score 0):

WireCloud supports using the [OAuth2 token provided by the IdM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299297/oauth2-in-wirecloud) to access third-party services, so the real problem is how to integrate Moodle with the IdM (as commented by @Meier).

There are some moodle plugins like [auth_googleoauth2](https://github.com/mouneyrac/moodle-auth_googleoauth2#implement-your-own-provider-for-devs) that supposedly offer support for adding your own OAuth2 providers. Take into account that probably you will need to make more modifications to this kind of plugins as usually the OAuth provider are only used for the sign in process, but this doesn't mean that you will be able to use the OAuth2 token as valid credentials for making request to the web service API.