# 502 (BAD GATEWAY) and 504 (GATEWAY TIMEOUT) in Wirecloud

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Time ago we set up a PEP proxy to secure the API our widgets are using. All have being working correctly until today, that we are receiving a 502 Bad Gateway error code for every call going through the proxy.

We have checked the requests are reaching our server and it is responsing correctly to them. The parameters added by the proxy (x-nick-name, x-display-name...) are defined correctly too.

We have also checked the requests outside wirecloud and all go well: we get the token properly and use it in the subsequent calls without problem.

We do not know where this error comes from, any ideas?

**EDIT 06/11/2015**

After Alvaro's new setting we are receiving the following error in the response body:

```
{
    "description": "Connection Error", 
    "details": "('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))"
}
```

**EDIT 09/11/15**

Today, the code received in the request's response is different: 504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT

```
{
    "description": "Connection Error",
    "details": "('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))"
}
```

**EDIT 16/11/15**

Answering to Mr. Alonso's question:

1.- If we request directly to the server, the response is correctly displayed in the application.

2.- [Here](http://pastebin.com/L3wJnhg9) you can see the logs from the PEP Proxy with the new line added. As you can see the request is redirected correctly but the info is not displayed in the app.

Comment: is your service running on https?

Comment: No, it isn't. I guess this is related with the warning you told me about in "Future Considerations" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299297/oauth2-in-wirecloud

Comment: No, we have not implemented nor deployed such validation, so definitely thats not the problem :). I asked you if your server was using https, because we reactivated https certs validation, so if you try to connect to a https server, it should use a valid cert (not a self-signed one)

is your service in the Spain2 node of the Cloud portal? are you observing this problem after the latest maintenance?

Comment: No, our service PEP Proxy is in Lannion2 and Wirecloud is the global instance. we observed this problem last wednesday

Comment: Ok, I've added more details to the error responses provided by the WireCloud's proxy. Please, try again and attach the error message so we can have more details about the error.

Comment: Álvaro, I edited the question to add the new information.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem is in the PEP proxy side.

I've checked using other tools like curl (I obtained the connection details from the server log). Making the same request using curl gives the same result than using WireCloud: connection reset by peer. Also, if I make the request without the `X-Auth-Token` header, your service responds with an 401 error code. This is important, because it means that there is not a communication problem between the Mashup portal and your server. I don't know why, but the PEP proxy seems to be crashing when making the authenticated request from the Mashup portal (the same command works executing it from my machine).

I suggest you to restart the PEP proxy. If the problem persist, please attach any available info about the crash from the PEP proxy logs.

Comment: We have restarted PEP Proxy but the problem is still there.After restarting we have set log level to debug and this is the results for a request from wirecloud http://pastebin.com/xgA2M8Jr

Comment: Today, the request's response code is different (see edit). We haven't done anything different. is it relavant?

Comment: No, the change in the error code is related to the changes I made for adding more info to the error response provided by the WireCloud's proxy. I'm contacting the PEP proxy team to see if they can help us with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check three things to give us more information:

- Try to remove the PEP and send the request directly to your service.
- Introduce a new log in PEP to print the headers of the response: line 41 of lib/HTTPClient.js, log.debug("Headers: ", headers);
- Try to send a request to the root path (directly to the tomacat or apache)

If not perhaps we can talk in private to check more information

Comment: We have detected a network problem in FIWARE Lab that may be related with your issue. Could you try again? have you tried the 3rd suggestion? is your vm hosted in fiware lab? which node?

Comment: ok i'm reading in other comment that the PEP is running in Lannion node. right?

Comment: Correct! About the 3rd suggestion, it isn't tested yet.

Comment: Alvaro, I have just tested your third suggestion and it works! I mean, the request is correctly returned passing through the proxy!

Comment: Hi,  definitely it seems a network problem in Lannion node. I will try to talk with them. BR

Comment: ÁlvaroAlonso, @nespapu, any progress? are the network problems in Lannion fixed?

Comment: @ÁlvaroArranz Unfortunately, the problem is still there. No progress in our side.